# How to using the Big object in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, big-object

I created big object through workbench. I want to create record using visualforce page using input fields in the big object. How is it possible? Could you please anybody help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your UI and insert record as any other object with consideration that you need to use **insertImmediate** method from Database class instead of insert or upsert

```
    // Define the record
    Customer_Interaction__b bo = new Customer_Interaction__b();
    bo.Account__c = '001R000000302D3';
    bo.Game_Platform__c = 'PC';
    bo.Play_Date__c = DateTime.newInstance(2018, 2, 5);
    bo.In_Game_Purchase__c = 'A12569';
    bo.Level_Achieved__c = '45';
    bo.Lives_This_Game__c = '3';
    bo.Score_This_Game__c = '5500';
    bo.Play_Duration__c = 25;

    // Insert the record, which creates a new record
    database.insertImmediate(bo);
```

You can read more about big object: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/big_objects/units/big_objects_define_custom_big_objects

Comment: I am trying above example, show in error. Because I need to upload Customer_Interaction zip file in workbench, In this time the object file can't be saved in OBJECT Type mode. This is saved only text format. How to convert that text file

Comment: Thankyou for giving quick reply. Could you provide Customer_Interaction__b zipfile.